# Forcing a task to start/ end 5 days before the next automatically - MS Project 2013

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management

I have a MS project that I'm working on. I have a same day task of "contact editor" that I ALWAYS want to occur 5 days before the next task "Media review". How do I do this and maintain dependencies so that if one day changes the changes waterfall through the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a finish to start link with 5 days lag.